# PHP strange behavior in function: displays/does not display text depending on English/Cyrillic text. Why?

Tags: php, function

There are two files run.php and class/functions.php that are used to put some text on html page (AJAX is used for that) on javascript event.

run.php file is:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

require_once('class/functions.php');

$text = array();
$text[0]="rrrrrr";

strange_func($text, 0);//puts "фа" into $text[0]
$res1=$text[0];

$arr = array();

$arr['res1'] = $res1;
$arr['res2'] = "test";

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

class/functions.php contains:

```
function strange_func(&$text, $i){
    $text[$i]="hello123";//hello123 will be displayed on html page on javascript event
    //$text[$i]="фь";
    //if we comment hello123 and uncomment фь, then фь will NOT be displayed on the html page on javascript event by unknown reason. Why?
}
```

Moreover, if I replace `require_once('class/functions.php');` with

```
function strange_func(&$text, $i){
    $text[$i]="фь";
}
```

, then "фь" will be displayed.
So, why the function `strange_func` from `class/functions.php` does not display text, if the text is Cyrillic?

The code above is the result of the simplifying and has no too much sense. But, the problem still exists.

Comment: I've been trying to recreate, but still can't. Are both files saved with utf-8 encoding (without BOM)? What version of php and server?

Comment: Wow, let me please double check it. I think I forgot about that when I created files in notepad++.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the problem was encoding in ANSI (default setting) instead of encoding in UTF-8 without BOM. You helped me to answer even more questions (had problems with « and » symbols either). How to accept your answer? Please post it not as a comment, but as an answer to my question so I can close it and choose the best answer. Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: I edited and undeleted the answer that I had previously. I deleted it because I read the question wrong and answered the wrong thing. You can change the default on notepad++ in settings->preferences->new doc/default dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save with utf-8 encoding (without BOM)